# How do I add multiple reactions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've looked everywhere for answers and I can't figure this out.

Here's what I want to do:

- I want to run some command initially for my bot to send an embed to a specific channel only admins have access to. Done.
- Then the bot will immediately react to its own message with the number emojis 1, 2, and 3. Problem.
- I don't want the bot to await a reaction to the message from an admin. This embed is meant to stay there UNTIL an admin reacts to it. That could be within 1 minute, or 3 days, but if I have to reboot the bot for any reason then it will stop awaiting the reaction. So I have an event that triggers when someone reacts with a given emoji, this works. It can be improved, but it functions:

```js
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", (messageReaction, user) => {
    console.log(messageReaction);
    if(reaction.emoji.name === "\u0031\u20E3") {
        message.channel.send('one'); //This is temporary to test it out. There will be other code here eventually.
    }
    else if(reaction.emoji.name === "\u0032\u20E3") {
        message.channel.send('two');
    }
    else if(reaction.emoji.name === "\u0033\u20E3") {
        message.channel.send('three');
    }
});
```

My problem is that when I run this code:

```js
let cmdEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle('**Command Menu Test**')
    .setDescription("Type commands")
    .setAuthor('InfernoBot', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/533089334224617474/17ddec7cb178601d17964040ed8dc32d.png?size=2048')
    .setColor(0xD41519);
message.channel.sendEmbed(cmdEmbed).then(function (message) {
    message.react('\u0031\u20E3')
    message.react('\u0032\u20E3') //This doesn't run
    message.react('\u0033\u20E3') //This doesn't run
});
```

It only ever reacts with the '1' emoji.

How do I make it react with emoji numbers 1, 2, and 3, without awaiting for a reaction?

PS: I'm going to implement some code that will resend the exact same embed with the same reactions once the existing embed has been reacted to, to reset it.

EDIT: The bot doesn't always react with 1. However, it only ever adds one reaction. It's not consistent.
[image: screenshot here]
.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer about 30 mins after posting this. I'll share for anyone who was having the same issue.

My first chunk of code in the original post was causing the bot to break and reboot.

I replaced the first chunk of code with:

```
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.toString() !== '<@533089334224617474>' /*InfernoBot ID*/) {
        console.log('User is not InfernoBot')
        if(reaction.emoji.name === "\u0031\u20E3") {
            //code here
        }
    }
});
```

And I replaced the second chunk of code with:

```
let cmdEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle('**Command Menu Test**')
    .setDescription("Type commands")
    .setAuthor('InfernoBot', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/533089334224617474/17ddec7cb178601d17964040ed8dc32d.png?size=2048')
    .setColor(0xD41519);
message.channel.sendEmbed(cmdEmbed).then(function (message) {
    message.react('\u0031\u20E3').then(() => message.react('\u0032\u20E3')).then(() => message.react('\u0033\u20E3'));
});
```

Comment: If your question is sloved then use the green tick next to your answer to mark it as best-answer and the question as solved

Comment: @PLASMAchicken I tried but it said I couldn't for 2 days, not sure why.